# Is there a jQuery Plug-in that simulates Facebook tours?

Tags: jquery, css, facebook

I mean "Facebook tours" for this:

[image: facebook tours]

Possibly with Facebook CSS out of the box.

I already know these two:

1. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/
2. http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

Both are missing: "Focus effect" (out of focus parts are lighter), Facebook CSS, tour bar on the top

About the CSS:
A possible solution could be http://ckrack.github.com/fbootstrapp/#popovers but Modals are not quite what I'm looking for (it's more a popup, no arrow, no "focus effect")

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case you use twitter bootstrap, here is a plugin for feature tours

- https://github.com/pushly/bootstrap-tour

Comment: It looks like this has been moved to a different github account: https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/

And the demo is now here:
http://sorich87.github.com/bootstrap-tour/

Answer (score 2):

I use [guiders.js](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS). It highlights the focused part. Also you can customize the CSS as it does not show facebook like modal dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

There are My two favorites ones:

- http://revaxarts-themes.com (see also http://revaxarts-themes.com/tour/examples/example6.html )
- http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/